# How to get job submission date from IBM workload scheduler (IWS)

Tags: scheduler

I use IWS to submit job but I want to get job submission date from IWS and assign it into the variable. Then, I want to use the variable parameter to pass date thru batch file.
I don't know how to do it. Can anyone suggest me about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you submit a job stream (even with a single job), the schedTime of the job stream is the by default the submission time.

From basic UNIX/Windows jobs, on FTA or dynamic agents, you can retrieve the schedTime with the environment variables `UNISON_SCHED_IA` (e.g 202210260856), or if only need the date with `UNISON_SCHED_DATE` (e.g. 20221026).

If you are using an Executable job type on a Dynamic agent you can get the same value with `${tws.job.iawstz}` variable.

Comment: Hi Mossotto, I'm appreciated it. Your answer is good, and I can apply it with my work.

Comment: Hi, I just tested but I found that `UNISON_SCHED_IA` is different from `UNISON_SCHED_DATE`. Moreover, I found that `TIVOLI_JOB_DATE` is different to them too. What exactly meaning of them? Can you explain me again?